# Special characters problem with database

Tags: php, database, magic-quotes

I am trying to add special characters into database with JavaScript  using `encodeURIComponent` but it works in localhost and in server adding `'` an extra `/` is also added infront of `'` .

How to prevent this?

---

This is what I have so far:

```
var qn_text = encodeURIComponent($('#question_text').val());
```

`question_text` is the field ID.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "<?= site_url('admin/inputdata')?>", 
                       data: "qn_text ="+qn_text, 
                       success: function(msg) { } 
      });
```

`admin` is my controller and then to model. If I enter special character like `+'&`, all these characters are entered in local database correctly. But at server side the characters like `'` entered but an extra `/` is appended  infront of `'` .

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. Show some code, some example data.

Comment: var text = encodeURIComponent(');i want to store this value of text into database.I passed this text through ajax to query.when trying to add into server db an extra / is appended to ' thats problem.but in localhost there no problem occured

Comment: That is not enough. Please describe the problem in more detail. Show some example data and what happens to it. (You can edit your question using the "edit" link)

Comment: @Rabeesh no problem, but this needs more information. Show a full example with example data

Comment: var qn_text = encodeURIComponent($('#question_text').val());

question_text is the feild ID.$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?= site_url('admin/inputdata')?>",
data: "qn_text ="+qn_text,
success: function(msg)
{
}
});admin is my controller and then to model.
i enter special charectar like +'&, all these charecters entered in  local database correctly.

but in server side the charectar like ' entered but an extra / is appented infront of ' that is my problem i want to store only '

Comment: You may have magic quotes enabled on the server. (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) - do edit your information into your question so others can see it straight away

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc enabled in my server, i just desabled it now all are works fine thank you very much my dear.

Comment: Ah, great. You're welcome. I'll add this as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable `magic_quotes` on your server. See [disabling magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in the PHP manual.